# \write18 with \csname not evaluating

Tags: shell-escape

I have noticed that the `write18` behaves differently when defined within a `csname`.

That is, given the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\csname textbf\endcsname{param} after

\csname write18\endcsname{sleep 10}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

I expected it to evaluate the shell command `sleep 10`, but instead it wrote it to the pdf stream. My best guess is this is a security mechanism to prevent obfuscation of `write18` commands, but am not sure.

P.S. latex is being invoked as `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
\csname write18\endcsname{sleep 10}
```

TeX builds a control sequence with name <kbd>`write18`</kbd>. (I use the keyboard symbol for clarity.) A side effect of `\csname...\endcsname` is that if the control sequence is undefined, it gets defined and its definition is `\relax`. The whole construct does nothing, and you are left with `{sleep 10}` which gets printed in the usual way.

`\write18` is something different: It's the (primitive) control sequence <kbd>`write`</kbd> followed by the number `18` (which then expects  a token list). The result you expect is obtained by

```
\csname write\endcsname18{sleep 10}
```

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote, but thanks, thats a nice answer.